# Annotate SQL Function to Django ORM Queryset `FUNC` / `AGGREGATE`

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm, timescaledb

I am trying to do something very similar to: [Annotate Custom SQL Function (similar to date_trunc) to Django ORM Queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46688158/annotate-custom-sql-function-similar-to-date-trunc-to-django-orm-queryset)

but have found the solution to be inadequate.

Using the same example as found in the prior link, suppose we have a Django model as such.

```
class Measurement(models.Model):

    device_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    s0 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    s1 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

We are trying to leverage the following in the ORM.

```
SELECT
  time_bucket('1 minute', time) AS tb,
  AVG(s0) 
FROM measurements
WHERE
  time >= to_timestamp(1) AND
  time <= to_timestamp(2)
GROUP BY tb
ORDER BY tb ASC;
```

We have a successful custom function as such:

```
class TimeBucket(Func):

    function = 'time_bucket'
    template = '%(function)s(\'{bucket_width}\', %(expressions)s)'.format(bucket_width='1 minute')
```

But we see that running a query like the following:

```
qs = (
    Measurement.objects
    .filter(...)
    .annotate(tb=TimeBucket('time'))
    .values('tb')
    .annotate(s_desc=Avg('s0'))
    .order_by('tb')
)
```

and checking its corresponding `qs.query` will always include `time` in the GROUP BY query. I **only** want to group by `tb`, the derived value, as shown in the original SQL. From what I'm reading, you need only use `values('tb')` as we are doing above to group by `tb`, but Django seems to append on `time` for some reason. Why is this the case?

Is it possible that my problem is less with this external function and more that I'm trying to group by a calculated field?

Comment: try droping the second annotate, and checking whether its still has group by time. I feel like its caused by Avg aggregate. But not sure.

Comment: That one doesn't have the `GROUP BY time` but defeats the purpose since I want to use this calculated field to compute other annotations. Even following something directly from the Docs of Timescale DB:
```
SELECT time_bucket('5 minutes', time) AS five_min, avg(cpu)
FROM metrics
GROUP BY five_min
ORDER BY five_min DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Becomes:
```
metrics.objects.values(five_min=time_bucket(time, "5 minutes")).annotate(avg_cpu=Avg("cpu"))
SELECT
    time_bucket('5 minutes', time) AS five_min,
    avg(cpu) AS avg_cpu
FROM metrics
GROUP BY time, time_bucket('5 minutes', time);
```

Comment: I'm silly! I had a default ordering in my model! It was causing it to add a GROUP BY by the ordered fields. Thank you!