# django custom Func for specific SQL function

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-queryset

I'm currently performing a raw query in my database because i use the MySQL function **instr**. I would like to translate is into a django Func class.
I've spend several days reading the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions), [Django custom for complex Func (sql function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46427115/django-custom-for-complex-func-sql-function) and [Annotate SQL Function to Django ORM Queryset `FUNC` / `AGGREGATE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62378989/annotate-sql-function-to-django-orm-queryset-func-aggregate) but i still fail to write succesfully my custom Func.
This is my database

```
from django.db import models
class Car(models.Model):
        brand = models.CharField("brand name", max_length=50)
#then add the __str__ function
```

Then I populate my database for this test

```
Car.objects.create(brand="mercedes")
Car.objects.create(brand="bmw")
Car.objects.create(brand="audi")
```

I want to check if something in my table is in my user input. This is how i perform my SQL query currently

```
query = Car.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM myAppName_car WHERE instr(%s, brand)>0", ["my audi A3"])
# this return an sql query with one element in this example
```

I'm trying to tranform it in something that would look like this

```
from django.db.models import Func
class Instr(Func):
        function = 'INSTR'

query = Car.objects.filter(brand=Instr('brand'))
```

**EDIT**

Thank to the response, the correct answer is

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import StrIndex
query = Car.objects.annotate(pos=StrIndex(Value("my audi A3"), "brand")).filter(pos__gt=0)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-contains

Comment: icontains and contains don't fit my needs because the user input contain some database entry and not the other direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom database function is totally correct, but you're using it in the wrong way.

When you look at your usage in the raw SQL function, you can clearly see that you need 3 parameters for your filtering to work correctly: a string, a column name and a threshold (in your case it is always zero)

If you want to use this function in the same way in your query, you should do it like this:

```
query = Car.objects.annotate(
    position_in_brand=Instr("my audi A3")
).filter(position_in_brand__gt=0)
```

For this to work properly, you also need to add `output_field = IntegerField()` to your function class, so Django knows that the result will always be an integer.

But... You've missed 2 things and your function is not needed at all, because it already exist in Django as [`StrIndex`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#strindex).

And the 2nd thing is: you can achieve the same outcome by using already existing django lookups, like `contains` or `icontains`:

```
query = Car.objects.filter(brand__contains="my audi A3")
```

You can find out more about lookups in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-contains)

Comment: thx for your response, first icontains don't fit my needs because i want to check if there are somme database brand `"bmw", "audi" or "mercedes"`contained inside the user input `"my audi A3"` and not the other direction.

Comment: There are also [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465858/django-reverse-to-contains-icontains/44682119) to achieve that using `contains` or `icontains`. You can also create your own lookup that will work in reverse.